why we need OAuthHandler when OpenIdConnectHandler can do the job?
OAuthHandler:
https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth/OAuthHandler.cs,2557205ecf41bef5
OpenIdConnectHandler:
https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectHandler.cs
The definitions of them are:
public class OpenIdConnectHandler : RemoteAuthenticationHandler<OpenIdConnectOptions>;

public class OAuthHandler<TOptions> : RemoteAuthenticationHandler<TOptions>;

// third party handler inherits OAuthHandler
public class FacebookHandler : OAuthHandler<FacebookOptions>;

Say I have a client app, and I need to connect to an idp (identityserver), then I just need to register OpenIdConnectHandler in my clientApp as:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    // ...        
})
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.Authority = "https://idpAddress";
    options.ClientId = "clientAppId";
    options.ClientSecret = "xxx";
    // ...
})

But if I need to integrate third party idp like Facebook, then I have to register in client app as
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook("Facebook", options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.AppId = "FacebookAppId";
    options.AppSecret = "xxx";
});

I don't quite understand the flow, why there is a need to have FacebookHandler and OAuthHandler while OpenIdConnectHandler can do the same job, I mean why can't we do:
// clientApp
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    // ...        
})
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.Authority = "https://facebookAuthorityEndpoint";
    options.ClientId = "FacebookAppId";
    options.ClientSecret = "xxx";
    // ...
})

Then we don't need FacebookHandler and OAuthHandler?

I guess it is because the AddFacebook adds a little extra support for anything more Facebook-specific (like some odd FB-specific claim). Even though AddOpenIdConnect would do the work.
Ii can also be that they wanted it to be simpler for beginners, where the terms/words used in the configuration better match what Facebook provides:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook("Facebook", options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.AppId = "FacebookAppId";
    options.AppSecret = "xxx";
});

If I am not wrong, both Facebook and the Google handler doesn't handle/support/allow signout for example? While AddOpenIdConnect does it.
